# Create a dictionary from one key and list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples. For example:

```
L = [(334, 269, 461, 482), (182, 178, 307, 471),(336, 268, 466, 483), (183, 177, 304, 470)]
```

The length of the list sometimes changes, it is not constant but the key is the same (for example, u'person')

```
key = u'person'
```

I tried to create the dictionary from the key and list, Unfortunately, it took the first tuple only.
the output was:

```
{u'person': (334, 269, 461, 482)}
```

Here, the value was as tuple but I would like the output will be:

```
{u'person': [(334, 269, 461, 482), (182, 178, 307, 471),(336, 268, 466, 483), (183, 177, 304, 470)]}
```

Here, the value is list of tuples.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried.

Comment: you can simply do ```dict_ = {u'person':L}```

Comment: Use the variables: `{key: L}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
new_dict = {u'person': L}
```

Output:

```
{u'person': [(334, 269, 461, 482), (182, 178, 307, 471),(336, 268, 466, 483), (183, 177, 304, 470)]}
```